# Prove that the linear transformation $R_n[x]\to R_{n-1}[x]$: $Δf(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ is an epimorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help to understand how proofs like these work. The book is so poorly written, there is no actual example for epimorphism, as all examples are unproven as *easily discernible*.

The exercise is ,as in the tittle, to prove that the linear transformation $R_n[x]\to R_{n-1}[x]$:  $(Δf)(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ is an epimorphism. I do not ask for the answer itself, I just want to understand how does someone proceed to prove this.

Comment: How does your book define [epimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism)? See the link for the official definition; my guess is the book just uses it as a posh term for "surjective linear map".

Comment: **F is an epimorphism if for every x ε F there is an f(x) ε F**. That is the exact (minus the symbol that denotes F as a space) sentence.

Comment: And this definition is a comment in the end sections of the book. The only explanation given (in the whole book) is that f is an epimorphism if it is "epi".Also, thank you for the edits. Could you please tell me how they are done?

Comment: As I suspected that is just the definition of a surjective map (probably also supposed to be linear in the context of the definition). The use of the term can be _justified_ by proving the property that for vector spaces, epimorphisms are precisely surjective linear maps, but even so using it here is confusing because it would seem to ask for proving (directly) that $f$ is right-cancellative rather than that is is surjective.

Comment: The book itself is generic, and not in a good way. In 60 pages it explained matrices, determinants, eigenvalues and spaces. Trying to understand those by the book, with no prior experience on them and without a teacher seems almost impossible. Thankfully, there is prof. Strang on youtube. But still, he can't cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

To prove it surjective, it suffices to exhibit that a generating system of the target space lies in the image of $\Delta$. This is often useful, e.g. in this particular case.